# Can I require Ruby libraries in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, gravatar

Can I do this HAML?

```
-require 'digest/md5'
.user-info
  =@user.name
  %img{ :src => "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@user.email)}" }
```

Comment: Whether or not you can, you shouldn't. This should be happening in a helper or in the model.

Comment: Did you try doing it?

Comment: I don't have access to my machine right now. And of course, this is not a clean way. Just wanted to know if we can include any random Ruby code in HAML or is it limited to a few constructs.

Comment: Check the docs. Anything with `-` in front of it is just treated as ruby. "I don't have access to my machine right now" is not a good reason to ask a question on stack overflow, if you have access to the internet you have access to the HAML docs and you can google for an answer. Ask questions on Stack Overflow after you've tried something and can't figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract this functionality on a helper file

```
require 'digest/md5'
class GravatarHelper
  def gravatar_image(email)
    image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email)}" )
  end

end
```

Then view becomes much clear

Comment: I'm really sorry if you feel that way. I have also accepted your answer because it was obviously the right way to do this. But I do not see anything wrong in finding out if there are obfuscated ways of doing things. If you don't, someone else would surely do it!